# Can't find the ActionBar resource icon

Tags: android

All, Forgive me I just began to learn development of Android, It is the first time I used the `ActionBar` in my Android application. Firstly.
I was following the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) to add the resource of ActionBar to project. But the IDE alert me the resource can't be found. please help to review my current setup. thanks.

I had downloaded and upziped all the [Icons](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#action-bar). and copy all the icons under the `res/drawable` folder.

[image]

and I add a xml file named `main_activity_actions.xml` under the folder `res/menu` which content shows below.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/Core_Icons/unstyled/hdpi/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />  
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" />

</menu>
```

Could someone please tell me why IDE can't find the icon `ic_action_search.png`? thanks.

Comment: Try building your project. Project -> Clean

Comment: And you have some error in the `res` folder it seems. First fix that. Otherwise, your project will not be built.

Comment: @Swayam The error still exist(can't found the icon) after rebuild project. thanks.

Comment: @Swayam There is no other error exist in the res folder, If I comment the definition of `item` , everything is fine . thanks.

Comment: Oh, okay. I suggested that because I saw the red cross mark on your res folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the resource folders do not support directory hierarchies (sub-folders), so you will need to move all icons to the parent folder (`drawable`).

Then reference it like this: `android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"`

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2018

Comment: No problem! It's annoying because it makes larger projects difficult to manage, but that's the way it is for now until they fix it...